# FirebaseTableView custom cell label is nil

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

when using the below with a standard UITableViewCell:

```
FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: self.db!.child("championships"), 
    cellReuseIdentifier: "championshipCell", view: self.tableView)
```

I can set the default label perfectly fine:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = championship.name
```

But when I try to use a custom cell with:

```
FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: self.db!.child("championships"), 
    cellClass: ChampionshipTableCell.self, 
    cellReuseIdentifier: "championshipCell", view: self.tableView)
```

and setting the custom label with:

```
let champCell = cell as! ChampionshipTableCell
champCell.championshipNameLbl.text = championship.name
```

I get an error saying "*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*" and I find that "champCell.championshipNameLbl" is nil.

I've confirmed the custom cell class is assigned to the cell in Storyboard and the IBOutlet is hooked up between Storyboard & custom class.

Any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: What line is causing nil? I assume label?

Comment: yeah - the "champCell.championshipNameLbl" is nil when i inspect it

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded FirebaseUI and issue went away when implementing FUICollectionViewDataSource instead